# How can I access the class variables inside the print() function here?

Tags: c++, oop

Book.h

```
class Book{
private:
    std::string title;
    std::string author;
    int callNo;
public:
    Book(std::string title,std::string author,int callNo);
    void print();

};
```

Book.cpp

```
Book::Book(string title,string author,int callNo){
    this->title=title;
    this->author=author;
    this->callNo=callNo;
}

void print(){
    cout<<"Title: "<<title<<endl;
    cout<<"Author: "<<author<<endl;
    cout<<"Call Number: "<<callNo<<endl;
}
```

When compiling, I get the error:

Book.cpp:14:19: error: ‘title’ was not declared in this scope
cout<<"Title: "<<title<<endl;

Is there anyway of calling the class variables without changing the parameters of print()?

Comment: You should write ```void Book::print(){...}```.

Comment: The print function in `Book.cpp` is not a member function. I think you want to change it to `void Book::print() { /*...*/ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a member function of Book, it should be

```
void Book::print(){
     std::cout << "Title: " << title << std::endl;
     std::cout << "Author: " << author << std::endl;
     std::cout << "Call Number: " << callNo << std::endl;
}
```